# AFNetworking AFAmazonS3Client issues uploading

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I am using the [Amazon S3 AFNetworking Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client) to attempt to upload files to S3 and I am running into troubles. I receive a bad URL response when running in simulator and a 405 response when running on a device. When receiving the 405 response, the log states 100% of the files are uploaded. I am unsure if I am going about this correct or not. This is my code:

```
    AFAmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[AFAmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:kAccessKeyID
                                                                        secret:kSecret];
    s3Client.bucket = kBucket;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.jpeg"];

    [s3Client postObjectWithFile:path parameters:nil progress:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100));
    } success:^(id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Upload Complete");
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but

```
AFAmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[AFAmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:@"kAccessKeyID"
                                                                    secret:@"kSecret"];
```

kAccessKeyId / kSecret are constants, yes? Generally you define constants as

```
#define kAccessKeyId @"myKeyId"
```

So you don't want to be adding additional quotes around them. I'm actually surprised the compiler is allowing it. Your line should look more like

```
AFAmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[AFAmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:kAccessKeyID
                                                                    secret:kSecret];
```

Some other general debugging:

- Log out the path you're trying to access and make sure you have the proper amount of slashes.
- A 405 error generally indicates the method you're using to access a particular URL isn't valid. Can you actually post / do you have permissions to post? This goes back to my point about where you might have accidentally added double-quotes when you don't need them, and thus will not be accessing your S3 storage correctly.

Comment: Sorry, edited that in stackoverflow so that I wasn't exposing the credentials and didn't realize the mistake! As far as permissions go, I have not altered anything since setting up a bucket nor have I created a bucket policy. Do I need to change anything or should the defaults be sufficient?

Comment: Changed it from POST to PUT and it is now working. Will accept your answer though.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I thought maybe a POST could have been the issue. Thanks for the accept.